# How to setup the Rippled server in my local?

Tags: ripple

Any body Please tell me how to setup the rippled server in my local system and how to call the API's for generating address and doing the transactions with out using the Rippled public server(s1.ripple.com   ).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple steps to setup ripple mainnet server in your system

You can also go through the link as below -

https://developers.ripple.com/install-rippled.html

**Minimum System Requirements**

A rippled server should run comfortably on commodity hardware, to make it inexpensive to participate in the network. At present, we recommend the following minimum requirements:

**Operating System:**

**Production:** CentOS or RedHat Enterprise Linux (latest release) or Ubuntu (16.04+) supported

**Development:** Mac OS X, Windows (64-bit), or most Linux distributions

**CPU:** 64-bit x86_64, 2+ cores

Disk: Minimum 50GB SSD recommended (1000 IOPS, more is better) for the database partition

**RAM:**

**Testing:** 8GB+

**Production:** 32 GB

Amazon **EC2's m3.large** VM size may be appropriate depending on your workload. A fast network connection is preferable. Any increase in a server's client-handling load increases resources needs.

**Installation on CentOS/Red Hat with yum**

This section assumes that you are using CentOS 7 or Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.

Install the Ripple RPM repository:

**$ sudo rpm -Uvh https://mirrors.ripple.com/ripple-repo-el7.rpm**

Install the rippled software package:

**$ sudo yum install --enablerepo=ripple-stable rippled**

Configure the rippled service to start on system boot:

**$ sudo systemctl enable rippled.service**

Start the rippled service

**$ sudo systemctl start rippled.service**

**Installation on Ubuntu with alien**
This section assumes that you are using Ubuntu 15.04 or later.

Install yum-utils and alien:

**$ sudo apt-get update**

**$ sudo apt-get install yum-utils alien**

Install the Ripple RPM repository:

**$ sudo rpm -Uvh https://mirrors.ripple.com/ripple-repo-el7.rpm**

Download the rippled software package:

**$ yumdownloader --enablerepo=ripple-stable --releasever=el7 rippled**

Verify the signature on the rippled software package:

**$ sudo rpm --import https://mirrors.ripple.com/rpm/RPM-GPG-KEY-ripple-release && rpm -K rippled*.rpm**

Install the rippled software package:

**$ sudo alien -i --scripts rippled*.rpm && rm rippled*.rpm**

Configure the rippled service to start on system boot:

**$ sudo systemctl enable rippled.service**

Start the rippled service

**$ sudo systemctl start rippled.service**

**Postinstall**
It can take several minutes for rippled to sync with the rest of the network, during which time it outputs warnings about missing ledgers. After that, you have a fully functional stock rippled server that you can use for local signing and API access to the XRP Ledger.

You can use the rippled commandline interface as follows:

**$ /opt/ripple/bin/rippled**

**Additional Configuration** (Must needs to do according your IP)-

rippled should connect to the XRP Ledger with the default configuration. However, you can change your settings by **editing the rippled.cfg file** (**located at /opt/ripple/etc/rippled.cfg** when installing rippled with yum). You must change the IP setting with your own entered IP and then connected with this setup server using java script code.

See the rippled GitHub repository for a description of all configuration options.

**Changes to the [debug_logfile] or [database_path]** sections may require you to give the rippled user and group ownership to your new configured path:

```
$ chown -R rippled:rippled <configured path>
```

Restart rippled for any configuration changes to take effect:

```
$ sudo service rippled restart
```

For more dig into ripple RPC and command kindly go through below link

https://developers.ripple.com/admin-rippled-methods.html

https://developers.ripple.com/public-rippled-methods.html

Hope this will help..